# Jquery using cookies to show and hide DIV

Tags: jquery

Hello I need hellp to set this up. Please!

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var shouldShow = $.cookie('show_languages') == 'yep';
            if(shouldShow) {
                $('.popupLang').show();
            } else {
                $('.popupLang').hide();
            }

            $('.popupLang').show();
            $.cookie('show_languages', 'yep');
            return false;

            $('#choose').click(function() {
                    $('.popupLang').hide();
                    $.cookie('show_languages', 'nope');
                    return false;
            });
});
```

**What I want:**

when page loads, i have a div container that is popup opening and covers the rest of the page, its class is "**popupLang**" when a link with id "**choose**" is clicked the container "**popupLang**" must hide, and cookies must remember this, so that when this page is opened again the DIV "**popupLang**" must remain HIDE.

What i must add in my code in order to make this?

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shouldShow = $.cookie('show_languages') != 'nope';
    $('.popupLang').toggle(shouldShow);

    $('#choose').click(function () {
        $('.popupLang').hide();
        $.cookie('show_languages', 'nope');
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

Your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //first time when the page loads the cookie value is undefined so the condition will fail
    var shouldShow = $.cookie('show_languages') == 'yep';
    if (shouldShow) {
        $('.popupLang').show();
    } else {
        $('.popupLang').hide();
    }

    //irrespective of the cookie value you are setting the visibility to true
    $('.popupLang').show();
    $.cookie('show_languages', 'yep');
    //you re returning here that means the click handler is never registered
    return false;

    //this code never gets executed
    $('#choose').click(function () {
        $('.popupLang').hide();
        $.cookie('show_languages', 'nope');
        return false;
    });
});
```